# Use LDAP on top of simple mysql hash+salt user table

Tags: ldap, authentication, sql

We have a huge table full of user accounts for our website that are stored in a very simple and standard mysql manner: the user-id is associated with a salted hash that represents the password and they both sit in a table next to each other.

We'd like to integrate with a couple of Atlassian tools that support LDAP for authentication but do not support our homebrew authentication. Is there a way that I could slap LDAP on top of our existing system for integration with these tools without enormous amounts of trouble? I don't care about all of the features of LDAP like group management and stuff, I just want someone to be able to type in the same username and password on an Atlassian website as on our corporate website and log in successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You'll want something like [`OpenLDAP's back-sql`](http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/backends.html#SQL).